# How to prevent Mocha from preserving require cache between test files?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, commonjs, supertest

I am running my integration test cases in separate files for each API.

Before it begins I start the server along with all services, like databases. When it ends, I close all connections. I use `Before` and `After` hooks for that purpose. It is important to know that my application depends on an enterprise framework where most "core work" is written and I install it as a dependency of my application.

I run the tests with Mocha.

When the first file runs, I see no problems. When the second file runs I get a lot of errors related to database connections. I tried to fix it in many different ways, most of them failed because of the limitations the Framework imposed me.

Debugging I found out that Mocha actually loads all files first, that means that all code written before the **hooks** and the `describe` calls is executed. So when the second file is loaded, the `require.cache` is already full of modules. Only after that the suite executes the tests sequentially.

That has a huge impact in this Framework because many objects are actually Singletons, so if in a `after` hook it closes a connection with a database, it closes the connection inside the Singleton. The way the Framework was built makes it very hard to give a workaround to this problem, like reconnecting to all services in the before hook.

I wrote a very ugly code that helps me before I can refactor the Framework. This goes in each test file I want to invalidate the cache.

```
function clearRequireCache() {
    Object.keys(require.cache).forEach(function (key) {
        delete require.cache[key];
    });
}

before(() => {
    clearRequireCache();
})
```

It is working, but seems to be very bad practice. And I don`t want this in the code.

As a second idea I was thinking about running Mocha multiple times, one for each "module" (as of my Framework) or file.

```
"scripts": {
   "test-integration" : "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha ./api/modules/module1/test/integration/*.integration.js && ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha ./api/modules/module2/test/integration/file1.integration.js && ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha ./api/modules/module2/test/integration/file2.integration.js"
}
```

I was wondering if Mocha provides a solution for this problem so I can get rid of that code and delay the code refacting a bit.

Comment: When you are saying `I install it as a dependency of my application.` do you mean you use `require` or `import` ? What do you mean by install ?

Comment: @Hosar yes, exactly